# React on fetch :: state not reflecting the recent changes in data after ADD or DELETE operations

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem where after fetching array is not updating properly.

```
      const [lists, setLists] = useState([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        getLists();
      }, []);
    
      function getLists() {
        const url = baseUrl + taskList + jsonEnd;
        fetch(url)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((json) => setLists(json));
      }

  function addList(name) {
    const url = baseUrl + taskList + jsonEnd;
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      header: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        Name: name,
      }),
    }).then(() => {
      getLists();
      getListNotes(lists[lists.length - 1].TaskListId);
    });
  }

  function deleteList() {
    const url = baseUrl + taskList + TaskListId + `/${currentList}` + jsonEnd;
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'DELETE',
      header: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' },
    }).then(() => {
      getLists();
      getListNotes(lists[lists.length - 2].TaskListId);
    });
  }
```

After adding a list to the list array and fetching the updated list array there should be x lists in the array however there are x-1. the reverse for deleting there is actually x but the function thinks there are x+1. However in the latter in the code when the lists are mapped over the array behaves correctly and there are the right amount of items.

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {TaskListId: 1, Name: "To do today"}
1: {TaskListId: 3, Name: "Constrains "}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)

(2) [{…}, {…}]
App.js:112 (2) [{…}, {…}]
App.js:112 (2) [{…}, {…}]
App.js:112 (2) [{…}, {…}]
App.js:112 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
```

**

```
{console.log(lists)}
        {lists.map((list, index) => (
          <List
            key={list.TaskListId}
            Name={list.Name}
            getList={getListNotes}
            setCurrentList={setCurrentList}
            TaskListId={list.TaskListId}
          />
        ))}
```

**

So I understand that the array is actually updating properly after fetch but in the then clause of the fetch, the list is not aware of the added item and vise versa for the delete where the list thinks the deleted item is still in the list.

I need the list to be aware of the proper membership in the fetch so that Io can render the added list on adding and I can render the predecessor of the deleted list on delete.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what dies getListNotes( ) do

Comment: async function getListNotes(ID) {
    const url = baseUrl + taskItem + TaskListId + `/${ID}` + jsonEnd;
    await fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setNotes(json));
  }

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 const [lists, setLists] = useState([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        getLists();
      }, []);
    
      async function getLists() {
        const url = baseUrl + taskList + jsonEnd;
        await fetch(url)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((json) => setLists(json));
      }

  async function addList(name) {
    const url = baseUrl + taskList + jsonEnd;
    await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      header: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        Name: name,
      }),
    }).then(() => {
      getLists();
      getListNotes(lists[lists.length - 1].TaskListId);
    });
  }

  async function deleteList() {
    const url = baseUrl + taskList + TaskListId + `/${currentList}` + jsonEnd;
    await fetch(url, {
      method: 'DELETE',
      header: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' },
    }).then(() => {
      getLists();
      getListNotes(lists[lists.length - 2].TaskListId);
    });
  }
```

Comment: I tried making the calls async but no change. I know that in a correct implementation both calls should take getListNotes(lists[lists.length - 1].TaskListId); since we want to render the last element of the array after the change but can't figure out why the change to the array isn't detected within the then clause.

Comment: try  useEffect(() => {
        getLists();
      }, [lists]);

Comment: still no change.